# Music ingestion time

Tags: android, gracenote

I have music that i can find using the text search api but I can't get it to be identified using the musicId-stream api . I have even tried to use the sample application to identify the song playing but just doesn't find it using the music-id functionality. Using the text search , i can find the song no problem.I have noticed also that in most of those cases, after 2 week or 3 weeks, I am able to identified  the song. I have come across similar situation many times and I was wondering if it is an expected scenario and if that is the case, what is the expected time delay?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not all the songs available through a text search are available with music-id simply because we do not have the fingerprints for *all* the songs that are in our music database.

There is no general rules about how fast things are available in the music-id database. Most of the times we are able to ingest the tracks even before the song is officially released. It depends on how fast the labels are submitting those tracks to us. The range is around one month before and one month after the track is released to public. But there are more constraints influencing track ingestion, for example, charts, trends, popularity and more. Sometimes for some reasons we do not get the tracks directly and have to acquire them. And then there is the ingestion queue we have. We are ingesting tens of thousands of tracks per week.

Now if you feel that a track is missing that really should be in there, you can alsways make a query and contact us through our support page : https://www.gracenote.com/support/

Comment: Thank for the detail response. It makes sense now. Are you guys planning anytime soon to allow developer  to create and maintain their own music-id database in addition to the Gracenote music-id database? This could be really usefull in cases where the songs have not been officially released but are already available on services like soundcloud like it is the case today

Comment: The latest version of our commercial SDK already have the possibility to use local caches but I'm unsure if the tools to generate those caches with custom content are going to be generaly available at some point. I doubt they will.